# Convert sites posts from BBCode to HTML in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, bbcode

So I'm working migrating a site from Xoops to Wordpress. I've worked out how to put my posts and categories em Wordpress database, but now I have a problem.
All posts in this site were edited in BBCode, and the field containing the articles have the BBCode tags and all. I have to convert that content to HTML fomating.
I've found a php script to convert the texts, but I have 500+ big articles, so I'm thinking about select all of those in a query and invoke the PHP script to do the conversion, get the return and update the fields.
But I don't quite know how to do it. I've tried somethings without success. Can I invoke the PHP scipt and get it's return to update my table?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you used in your attempt?

Comment: Why don't you convert them at the moment they're being displayed? That allows for editing of the posting as well.

Comment: Hey guys! So, I've decided to do it in a diferent way, using a php script to do all the job. But I have a problem. I use CPanel, and for some reason, even after I authenticate myself with the specific user for the database, when I do the query I got and error regardind my main CPanel user. What should I do?